# Metric induced Topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The Problem: Given a metric space $(X,d)$, define a new metric $d'$ on X by $$ d'(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{d(x,y)+1} $$ Is the topology induced by $d'$ the same as the topology induced by d? Prove or disprove.

My Work: This problem is actually on our review sheet for the midterm. I am having trouble understanding this problem because we have not talked at all about metric induced topologies in class. Any help in understanding this concept would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Show the transformation between two metrics and its inverse are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

The topology induced by a metric is given as the open sets correspond to the "open balls" relative to the metric. So given $x_0 $ and $c$ the set $U=\{ x  | d(x,x_0)<c \}$ would be open.